# R Session Aborted when loading package

Tags: r, rstudio, ggvis

My RStudio (0.99.879, R 3.2.3, OSX 10.11.3) crashes with the `R Session Aborted` error box every time I run `require(ggvis)` (v0.4.2).  I've reinstalled R, RStudio and ggvis - no change.  Any idea what's causing this, or how to traceback?

Running `Sys.getenv()` gives me [this report](http://pastebin.com/raw/VqrTtNR8), if it helps.

Comment: Does it help if you try re-installing the dependencies of `ggvis` as well? E.g. `deps <- tools::package_dependencies("ggvis", db = available.packages())$ggvis; install.packages(deps)`

Comment: Oooh that worked, thanks!  Wasn't aware of `tools::package_dependencies `.. Want to add as answer for the tick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes startup errors like this can be caused by out-of-date dependent packages. You can try updating the packages that `ggvis` depends on with:

```
db <- available.packages()
deps <- tools::package_dependencies("ggvis", db)$ggvis
install.packages(deps)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should increase the memory size. This will solve your problem.
memory.limit(size=4096) #This will make the memory 4MB

Comment: This question was already answered and the answer was accepted, so I don't see how your answer can be correct.

Comment: @Garima-Singh IMO you should ignore that comment. Subsequent answers can often be better than those accepted. And welcome to SO :)

Comment: The OP is using a Mac but memory.limit() only has an effect on Windows.