# Call to library(raster) or require(raster) causes Rstudio to abort session

Tags: r, rstudio, r-raster

I've used the raster package before on my computer but recently, any calls to library(raster) or require(raster) are causing Rstudio to abort the session - "R session aborted. R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated".

I've tried removing packages and reinstalling. install.package("raster") worked but then library or require calls to raster cause the session to abort. I've also tried restarting both rstudio and my computer.

Working on a Mac - Mojave version 10.14.6. Rstudio version 1.2.1335. R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)

I've also tried updating the packages that raster depends on as suggested by this thread - [R Session Aborted when loading package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536035/r-session-aborted-when-loading-package) but that did not solve the problem.

Is this just an update problem? My mac and R versions aren't that old. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion here: https://github.com/rspatial/raster/issues/63

It seems to me that the best approach is to install a fresh R (you are a couple of versions behind anyway) and fresh packages.