# response.plot3() crashes RStudio

Tags: r, crash, rstudio, raster, abort

**0. Session information**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
```

**1. Summary of my issue**

I am having a crash while using a modified function of `response.plot2()`, named `response.plot3()`. The problem is not the function in itself, as the same problem occurs with `response.plot2()`.

[image]

**2. Code**

```
library(biomod2)
library(raster)
library(reshape)
library(ggplot2)

setwd("xxx")

# I load the modified version of response.plot2()
source("/response.plot_modified.R", local = TRUE)

sp <- "NAME"
baseline_EU <- readRDS("./data/baseline_EU.rds")

initial.wd <- getwd()
setwd("models") 

# Loading of formatted data and models calibrated by biomod
load(paste0(sp, "/run.data"))
load(paste0(sp, "/model.runs"))

# Variables used for calibration
cur.vars <- model.runs@expl.var.names
  
# Loading model names into R memory
models.to.plot <- BIOMOD_LoadModels(model.runs)
 
# Calculation of response curves with all models (stored in the object resp which is an array)
resp <- response.plot3(models = models.to.plot,
                         Data = baseline_EU[[cur.vars]],
                         fixed.var.metric = "sp.mean",
                         show.variables = cur.vars,
                         run.data = run.data)
```

I have got 60 models and the code plot the first curve before aborting the session, with no further explanation.

**3. What I unsuccessfully tried**

(1) check that it was not a ram issue
(2) uninstall-reinstall all the packages and their dependencies
(3) uptade to the last R version
(4) go back to `response.plot2()` to see if the issue could come from `response.plot3()`

**4. I found some similar errors which lead me to think that it might be a package issue**

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9373

[Call to library(raster) or require(raster) causes Rstudio to abort session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599090/call-to-libraryraster-or-requireraster-causes-rstudio-to-abort-session)

Now I presume that there is a problem either with the biomod2 or the raster packages, or maybe the R version?

I would greatly appreciate your help if you have any ideas.

Comment: If I recall correctly you're reposting this question? Unfortunately there's really very little we can do without a [mcve] ... see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  In particular, (1) we don't have data; (2) we have no idea what's in your modified plotting code (`response.plot_modified.R`). The RStudio crash you're seeing is very generic; your linked questions don't necessarily have much in common with your problem ... The only thing I can suggest to try is to run your code in a plain R console, to confirm ...

Comment: ... or rule out the suggestion that it's RStudio-specific. Your first link provides a pointer to a patched release of RStudio that should solve the problem if it *is* related to the combination of R 4.1.0 + ggplot2 + RStudio ... https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: Does your code work if you run it in R directly (i.e. NOT using Rstudio)?

Comment: @BenBolker yes you recall correctly, I realized that my question at the time was not clear enough, which I tried to correct in the past few days. I will try to run in a plain R console as suggested by you and Phil and I will try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @BenBolker & Phil, thank you for your contribution, the code runs using just a plain R console! So it is RStudio-specific? Any tips on where to look for?

Comment: did you install the patched RStudio from [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) ?

Comment: This is maybe related to 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67627539/r-4-1-0-crashes-when-trying-to-ggplot


I have the same problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed)) +
  geom_histogram()
```

See screnn capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGMGk.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638836/r-crashing-while-displaying-ggplot-after-update-process-memory-read-out-of-rang/67638944#67638944

Comment: It's *likely* that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67638836/r-crashing-while-displaying-ggplot-after-update-process-memory-read-out-of-rang/67638944#67638944 , but ideally we would get confirmation from the OP (i.e., a statement that downgrading to R 4.0x or installing the patched version of RStudio resolved the problem)

Comment: I am sorry, I had to use my computer for long running codes, but I will try to install the patched RStudio as soon as possible and keep you updated. Regarding the R version, I had the same issue with R 4.0 and installed the newest version 4.1 and had the same problem.

Comment: @BenBolker, as your answer of using a plain R console was enough to get past my issue, if you want to post it as an answer I can give you the tick ;)